# Pretty print value table from BigQuery Standard SQL joined tables using bq on CLI?

Tags: join, google-bigquery, bq

Is there a way to pretty format Big Query "value table" result sets with the `bq` command line tool using Standard SQL? This works as expected in the BigQuery console with Standard SQL but not in bq. I cannot find a convenient workaround. It also works as expected using Legacy SQL.

My use case: I am exploring tables with large numbers of columns in BigQuery. Anonymous queries in BigQuery require that the selected columns be uniquely named, otherwise you get the message "Duplicate column names in the result are not supported. Found duplicate(s):...". This is a very strict requirement when I am just exploring the data. Fortunately, there is a way around this in the BigQuery web console by using value tables in the select expression...

```
with
left_side as
(
select 1 as id, 'hello' as col1 union all 
select 2 as id, 'there' as col1
)
,right_side as
(
select 1 as id, 'hello' as col1 union all 
select 2 as id, 'world' as col1
)
select a, b
  from left_side a
       join
       right_side b
          on a.id = b.id
```

... which results in the following tabular result set with the columns automatically enumerated which is excellent...

[image: tabular result set]

However the exact same query when passed to `bq` on the command line as follows (via a here document for your convenience). Normally, I have the query in a file and redirect it into `bq`, for example, `bq query --use_legacy_sql=false < bq_test4.sql`

```
bq query --use_legacy_sql=false <<BQ_TEST
with
left_side as
(
select 1 as id, 'hello' as col1 union all 
select 2 as id, 'there' as col1
)
,right_side as
(
select 1 as id, 'hello' as col1 union all 
select 2 as id, 'world' as col1
)
select a, b
  from left_side a
       join
       right_side b
          on a.id = b.id
BQ_TEST
```

...results in this same essential result set regardless of any `--format` options passed to `bq`...

```
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|             a             |             b             |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| {"id":"1","col1":"hello"} | {"id":"1","col1":"hello"} |
| {"id":"2","col1":"there"} | {"id":"2","col1":"world"} |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
```

Such a result set is not helpful to me.

Ok, I can convert the json to a tabular result set with...

```
with
left_side as
(
select 1 as id, 'hello' as col1 union all 
select 2 as id, 'there' as col1
)
,right_side as
(
select 1 as id, 'hello' as col1 union all 
select 2 as id, 'world' as col1
)
select json_extract_scalar(to_json_string(a), "$['id']") as `a_id`
      ,json_extract_scalar(to_json_string(a), "$['col1']") as `a_col1`
      ,json_extract_scalar(to_json_string(b), "$['id']") as `b_id`
      ,json_extract_scalar(to_json_string(b), "$['col1']") as `b_col1`
  from left_side a
       join
       right_side b
          on a.id = b.id
```

... which results in and which is exactly what Legacy SQL would produce...

```
+------+--------+------+--------+
| a_id | a_col1 | b_id | b_col1 |
+------+--------+------+--------+
| 1    | hello  | 1    | hello  |
| 2    | there  | 2    | world  |
+------+--------+------+--------+
```

Having to enumerate the columns defeats the intention of my use case.

Is there any way, while using Standard SQL, of avoiding enumerating the columns either prior to my join or after my join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still requires some typing  - but less verbose version

```
#standardSQL
WITH left_side AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'hello' AS col1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'there' AS col1
), right_side AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'hello' AS col1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2 AS id, 'world' AS col1
)
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT NULL a_id, NULL a_col1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM left_side) a
JOIN (SELECT NULL b_id, NULL b_col1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM right_side) b
ON a_id = b_id
```

with result

```
Row a_id    a_col1  b_id    b_col1   
1   1       hello   1       hello    
2   2       there   2       world
```

so will be as below in bq...

```
+------+--------+------+--------+
| a_id | a_col1 | b_id | b_col1 |
+------+--------+------+--------+
| 1    | hello  | 1    | hello  |
| 2    | there  | 2    | world  |
+------+--------+------+--------+
```

Comment: Yes, that's a neat workaround - thank you - and I suppose I could auto-generate the column list but I did want to avoid that. Do you know if this is considered to be a known issue in bq? My other alternative is to write my own bq in python and handle the json conversion there.

Comment: 1) yes - i don't see way to avoid generating (manually or via code) columns list. 2) I am not sure -  but most likely this is not considered as a issue for Standard SQL - but you can post feature request so they will consider :o)

Comment: Did auto-generate column list as per your suggestion re NULL by shelling out from vim to query information_schema passing fully qualified tablename and alias as args. Works nice, but verbose and involves munging the join condition. Also implemented in python to detect dict in [0,0] (can rework later to inspect presence of dict on all cols) and iterate to recast as DataFrame. Must nicer, more versatile, and means I don't have to mess around with my SQL. Thanks for your suggestions. I might have a look at logging a feature request... would be a useful option on bq command.